# Setting AlertDialog with complex string-array resource

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, arrays

I have a simple alert dialog as shown below working with a simple string-array (a). I'd like to replace, (a) with a more complex string-array (b) but I am getting a null pointer exception when the dialog tries to resolve the view.

Is this possible or have I done something wrong?

(a)

```
AlertDialog Code:

  final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(ctx,   R.style.mytheme));
  dialog.setTitle(title);
  dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  dialog.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.array_items, -1, itemSelectedListener);
  final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();

array_items.xml:

  <string-array name="array_items">
    <item>option a</item>
    <item>option b</item>
  </string-array>
```

(b)

```
array_items_2.xml:

  <string-array name="array_items_2">
    <item>@array/array_items.xml</item>
    <item>@array/array_items.xml</item>
  </string-array>
```

The second xml will cause the AlertDialog to crash with a NullPointerException.

Have I made a mistake or is this not possible with the AlertDialog without a custom view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good point ,but not possible ! For this you have to maintain your xml file containing all the information/relation you want to have as static data and grammatically you will have to parse the file and extract information.Other possible ways are SQLite but i won't suggest you to try that because there is no meaning to maintain a table if you are not going to do CRUD operations or so.